# obtain all non zero solutions for a linear system

Tags: matrices

Is it possible to find the solutions of a non-symmetric, non-square matrix ? If so, how do I know if it has infinite, unique or no solutions ??
The given linear system is :
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & -1 & 3\\[1ex]
-2 & 4 & 5 & -5\\[1ex]
3 & -6 & -6 & 8
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\[1ex]
x_2 \\[1ex]
x_3\\[1ex]
x_4
\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\[1ex]
3\\[1ex]
2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I can't understand what the linear system is. Could you write it using MathJax?

Comment: just corrected it.  Sorry , I am new to this and I was not sure of the format.

Comment: I suppose the first formula is the matrix of the system?

Comment: yes it is.  It is in the from Ax = b , where A is the matrix, x are the unknowns and b is the right side of the equation.

Comment: I took the liberty to make your formulæ more standard, and had to rewrite part of it to make things consistent. Feel free to revert back if it's not fine for you. This being said, you have to write the augmented matrix and  transform it  into  reduced row echelon form.

Comment: Still not familiar with MathJax  I will pick it up eventually.  Thank you

Comment: If you happen to know LaTeX, it looks more or less like a small subset thereof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint 1:** if $Ax=b$ but $A$ is not square, then multiply both sides by $A^{\text{T}}$.

**Hint 2:** The third row of $A$ is actually the first row minus the second row, but the same is not true for $b$; that is a bad omen.

Comment: ${}$Bad for what?